# Tolerances given for Galactic Directions in answer to 'How fast are we moving relative to the CMB?'

Tags: observational-astronomy, cosmic-microwave-background

Question: Tolerances given for [Galactic Directions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_coordinate_system), in answer to 'How fast are we moving relative to the [CMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background)?'

Where:

$$ℓ = 264.021º ± 0.011º$$
$$ =  48.253º ± 0.005º$$

I can find these values on the net, but I cannot find the tolerances given here.

The link given: [Planck Collaboration et al. (2018)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2020A&A...641A...6P/abstract), does not give any such information.

Can you help please?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you want?  It's not clear to me what you mean. (1) "I can find these values on the net"  Please link to the place on the net where you can find the values.  (2)  "I cannot find the tolerances given here."  Where is "here"?  What do you mean by "tolerances"?   (3) "The link given <<. Planck Collaboration et al. (2018) >>"  This isn't a link,  it isn't a full citation.  What link are you asking about?

Comment: I hope you will add this information and clarify the question. If not I'll have to vote to close, as I don't think it is clear enough to answer.

Comment: The numbers you quote have error bars, which seem like perfectly valid "tolerances". So, again, it's not clear what you're asking about.

Comment: The link given is incomplete.  I can find a link to a pdf, << arXiv:2009.14826v2 [astro-ph.CO] 18 Jan 2021 >> but though it gives the values, there are no tolerances.  Can you please direct me to the correct link, for I cannot find the details you are referring to.